# How to get IBInspectable var value with get return?

Tags: ios, swift, ibinspectable

I have simple rating app and i have;

```
 @IBInspectable var commingId: Int
        {
        get
        {
            return self.commingId;
        }
        set
        {
            refreshStars()
        }
    }


func starClicked(sender:UIButton){
    if(self.canEdit){
        rating = sender.tag;
        if(self.delegate != nil){
            self.delegate.starRateEdited(Double(rating))
        }

        self.refreshStars()
        print("Selected \(sender.tag) - commingId \(self.commingId)")



    }
}
```

codes. when i try to get return `self.commingId` gives me;

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x7fff571egff8) error

How can i get `commingId` inside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why do you even redefined getter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

It looks like you just need to call `refreshStars()` after value is set, so just work with `willSet/didSet`

```
@IBInspectable var commingId: Int {
    didSet {
        refreshStars()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Following :

```
var commingRating: Int = 0

@IBInspectable var commingId: Int
            {
            get
            {
                return self.commingRating;
            }
            set
            {
                commingRating = newValue
                refreshStars()
            }
        }


    func starClicked(sender:UIButton){
        if(self.canEdit){
            rating = sender.tag;
            if(self.delegate != nil){
                self.delegate.starRateEdited(Double(rating))
            }

            self.refreshStars()
            print("Selected \(sender.tag) - commingId \(self.commingId)")



        }
    }
```